# AFHTTPRequest for public S3 file fails for some users

Tags: amazon-s3, afnetworking

I have a bucket full of public files accessed through my app. The app downloads a batch of these files with `AFHTTPRequestOperation` through an `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`. For almost all users, this works smoothly without any problems. For a very small number of users, all of the downloads fail with a variety of error messages.

Most of the error messages are `Request failed: not found (404)`, and about 5-10% are `The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)`, `The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory`, and `The network connection was lost`.

The users who experience the failures get the same failure any time they try downloading the files again, until they delete the app and reinstall. Other users with the same app download the files without any trouble.

Here is the code used for downloading the files:

```
-(void)beginDownloadsHTTP {
  NSString *baseURL = @"https://s3.amazonaws.com/";
  _afHTTPManager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL]];

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    [self downloadOneFileHTTP:_fileKeys.anyObject];
  }
}

-(void)downloadOneFileHTTP:(NSString *)oneKey {
  [_fileKeys removeObject:oneKey];
  NSString *baseURL = @"https://s3.amazonaws.com/";
  NSString *plusKey = [oneKey stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
  NSString *downloadURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%@", baseURL, _bucketName, plusKey];

  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:downloadURL]];
  NSString *downloadPath = [self downloadPathForItem:oneKey];      

  AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [_afHTTPManager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    if (_fileKeys.count > 0) {
      [self downloadOneFileHTTP:_fileKeys.anyObject]; 
    }

  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self fileDidFailWithKey:oneKey andError:error];

  }];
  op.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
  op.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:downloadPath append:NO];
  [_afHTTPManager.operationQueue addOperation:op];
}
```

Any ideas for what's causing the problem? It seems like there's some setting stored in the phone that's causing the particular set of files to always fail, and deleting the app clears that setting, but I have no idea where to look for it.

Comment: Which commonality do the users with the failed requests have? Think of firewall, proxy, blocked ports...

Comment: Wouldn't any of those things cause the user to never be able to download ANY of the files in ANY of the folders, though? Unless the user was behind a firewall for one folder download, but not for the others. Either way, would there be a way to reset the connection at some later point so the user can download the folder when no longer behind the firewall or proxy?